# How to do location wise product display in Django for eCommerce site

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I want to know What is the best way for displaying products location wise in eCommerce website like used in these websites

```
(https://www.walmart.com/)
(https://grofers.com/)
(https://www.bigbasket.com/)
```

Please share any eCommerce opensource project of Django where this kind of location filtering is done